# websphere 7 JMS connection pool; grows and grows

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq

I'm running websphere 7 (fixpack 7.0.0.1.9) & websphere-mq7 (fixpack 7.0.1.5).

I've set the connection pool for both my FACTORIES (FACTORY and MQ_FACTORY) to...

FACTORY

```
Connection timeout : 180   seconds
Maximum connections : 10   connections
Minimum connections : 1    connections
Reap time : 180  seconds
Unused timeout 1800  seconds
Aged timeout  0  seconds
Purge policy :EntirePool
```

MQ_FACTORY

```
Connection timeout : 180   seconds
Maximum connections : 10   connections
Minimum connections : 1    connections
Reap time : 180  seconds
Unused timeout 1800  seconds
Aged timeout  0  seconds
Purge policy :EntirePool
```

The PMI tool shows the following...

```
JCA Connection Pools...
CreateCount : 27.0
CloseCount  : 4.0
PoolSize    : 23.0

JMS Connection Factories
CreateCount : 14.0
CloseCount  : 2.0
PoolSize    : 12.0

Websphere MQ JMS Provider
CreateCount : 13.0
CloseCount  : 2.0
PoolSize    : 11.0
```

HOW is my connection pool bigger than the pool size?!?!?!
HOW come the pool size remains high???

The more messages I send in, the bigger it gets.

So for example, I've just sent in a load more messages and now my sizes are...

```
JCA Connection Pools...
CreateCount : 35.0
CloseCount  : 0.0
PoolSize    : 35.0
FreePoolSize: 14.0

JMS Connection Factories
CreateCount : 15.0
CloseCount  : 0.0
PoolSize    : 15.0
FreePoolSize: 0.0

Websphere MQ JMS Provider
CreateCount : 20.0
CloseCount  : 0.0
PoolSize    : 20.0
FreePoolSize: 14.0
```

Here are the stats for the factories...

```
JMS$MQ_FACTORY
    CreateCount : 6.0
    CloseCount  : 0.0
    PoolSize    : 6.0
    FreePoolSize: 5.0

JMS$FACTORY
    CreateCount : 14.0
    CloseCount  : 4.0
    PoolSize    : 10.0
    FreePoolSize: 5.0

jms/MQ_FACTORY
    CreateCount : 6.0
    CloseCount  : 0.0
    PoolSize    : 6.0
    FreePoolSize: 0.0

jms/FACTORY
    CreateCount : 9.0
    CloseCount  : 0.0
    PoolSize    : 9.0
    FreePoolSize: 0.0
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks
Jeff Porter

Answer (score 0):

The "JCA Connection Pools" represents the totals for the "JMS Connection Factories" and "WebSphere MQ JMS Provider." (Notice that the sum of these two individual stats equals the stats in the "JCA Connection Pools.")

Also, the connection pooling settings are for *each* configured connection factory, and the "JMS Connection Factories" and "WebSphere MQ JMS Provider" statistics represent the sum for all submodules (i.e. for all connection factories). Given that you stated "I've set the connection pool for *both* my FACTORY" (emphasis mine), I'm assuming that you actually have two different connection factories, which could explain why these values are higher than each individual connection factory's max connections.

If you are using the *Performance Viewer* in the ISC, you should be able to expand each module to view the individual submodules. If you are checking the stats through `wsadmin`, you will need to grab the substats (`getSubStats`) for the JCA modules.

Comment: you are correct, I'll update my question above. I have two factory, but the totals are greater than the two of them.

Comment: Can you provide the stats for the individual factories as well? I still don't see pool sizes in your updated question that are greater than the expected sum of multiple factories' pool sizes.

Comment: Maybe the point of confusion here is the difference between the connection pools and session pools? Note that each of your connections also has its own session pool. You can view these settings at: Resources > JMS > [Queue] Connection factories > [your connection factory] > Session pools. The stats you're looking at are for all connection and session pools for all your connection factories.

Comment: Here are a couple links to some IBM documentation that might be helpful:

[Explanation of connection pool and session pool settings for JMS connection factories](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21201242), 

[JMS connection pools and sessions pools in WebSphere Application Server](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21168924)

Answer (score 0):

please check in your code, if you had closed the QueueConnection, incase you open. Please make sure the connection is closed in any scenario, no matter if there is also any exception after the connection is created and started.

Comment: This should have been a comment, not an answer.